# Remove overlapping days And arrange dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with the following data

```
Start       End         
=====       ===         
12/21/2011  12/20/2012   
05/05/2012  10/20/2013
12/21/2012  12/20/2013   
12/21/2013  12/20/2014
12/21/2014  12/20/2015
```

And want to get the following results

```
Start       End        
=====       ===        
12/21/2011  05/04/2012 
05/05/2012  10/20/2013
10/21/2013  12/20/2013
12/21/2013  12/20/2014
12/21/2014  12/20/2015
```

Any ideas on where to start? A lot of the reading I've done suggests I need to create entries and for each single day once and remove overlapping days and manage date accordingly. is this the only way?

Comment: what version of SQL server are you on?

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear. You posted two tables, do you want us to look for the differences?

Comment: Look into using the LAG() function.

Comment: By removing overlapping days, a segment or period of time (in other words, a row of the table) can become into two or more periods as you iterate trough the table. This splitting process is too complicated and inefficient. I vote for the day by day classic solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this kind of problem is better solved in some sort of procedural approach, also for the sake of readability. Nevertheless, for fun, I figured out an SQL statement that does the trick with the aid of the rownum statement (in Oracle syntax, as I had no sql-server database at hand):

Let's assume your table is called `DATE_TABLE` with columns `START_DATE` and `END_DATE`. Then the statement is as follows:

```
select start_date,
       coalesce(
          (select case when tbl_inner.start_date < tbl_outer.end_date
                       then tbl_inner.start_date - 1
                       else tbl_outer.end_date end
           from   (select rownum row_num, start_date, end_date from date_table order by 1) tbl_inner
           where tbl_inner.row_num = tbl_outer.row_num + 1),
           tbl_outer.end_date)
from   (select rownum row_num, start_date, end_date from date_table order by 1) tbl_outer;
```

The inner select provides the rows of the table `DATE_TABLE` with row numbers that can be referenced by the outer select. Without the `COALESCE` clause, the statement would not work for the last row in the `DATE_TABLE`.

I presume that the statement does not scale too well.